# LinkedIn API - ACCESS_DENIED - Not enough permissions to access

Tags: authentication, permissions, linkedin-api, access-denied

When I requested the `/rest/me` LinkedIn API endpoint...

```
curl --location 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/me' /
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' /
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {MY_TOKEN}' /
--header 'LinkedIn-Version: 202306'
--header 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0'
```

I got an error...

```
{
    "status": 403,
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiMe.GET.20230601"
}
```

My access token had the permission scope listed in the API docs (`r_liteprofile`). So, I sent a message to the LinkedIn Developer Support team, and they said...

> ... support for r_liteprofile was dropped from version 202306 onward, but we are trying to get official confirmation of that decision to get documentation updated. The minimal permissions allowed for /me access would now be r_basicprofile going forward.

Got it. API docs were wrong. So, I changed the permission from `r_liteprofile` to `r_basicprofile`, generated a fresh access token, but I still got the same error.

A few hours later, I test the code again, and it worked! But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The "Fix"

After you change permissions, **wait at least 5 minutes before testing**.

### Why?

There is [a caching bug with LinkedIn API access tokens](https://github.com/twobitfool/linkedin-auth-bug/?tab=readme-ov-file#linkedin-api-auth-problem).

Generating a new access token *SHOUD* invalidate the previous token, but there is a 5 minute window when your new token might behave like an old token (using old permissions / scopes).

**This makes LinkeIn API development very difficult.** Any time a developer makes a change to the permission scopes, new tokens may throw (invalid) permission errors for several minutes, making it seem like the scope change didn't make any difference. Then a few minutes later, the new permissions will unexpectedly kick in, making it hard to reproduce the bug.

### Bug Reported

I reported this to the LinkedIn Developer Support team with [an app to prove it](https://github.com/twobitfool/linkedin-auth-bug/), and they responded...

> After much discussion, team has confirmed they will consider this as part of product improvement but for now 5mins TTL is expected behavior. **Developers usually don't have this pattern of trying to generate token for different combination of permissions. This is more like rare use case.**
>
> For now we have added this feedback to our roadmap. Unfortunately, we don't have concrete timeline as to when this will be implemented into production

I disagree. **Changing permissions and generating new tokens is something that developers will do often**, as they try to figure out what permissions are required for different API calls. I know I did it many times, especially after finding out that some of the API docs weren't being kept up to date... just had to keep remembering to wait 5 minutes before testing.

**If you run into this issue** please [report the bug to LinkedIn](https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new), so they will see how many developers are bumping into this problem.

### Version Upgrade Warning

This also creates a problem when upgrading the `LinkedIn-Version`. In version `202306`, they changed the permission required on the `/rest/me` endpoint -- from `r_liteprofile` to `r_basicprofile`. This means that we will have to ask some customers to reauthorize their LinkedIn account, to get a new access token (with `r_basicprofile` scope). But they might run into this caching bug, and get permission errors, if their old token (with `r_liteprofile`) was used in the past 5 minutes.